# Executing jbehave test, some steps pending unexpectedly in JUnit report

Tags: eclipse, jbehave, user-stories

I'm newbie to JBehave. Followed the tutorial and create all classes, including steps as well as stories, then run it. For some reason, as can be seen from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69XfA.png).

don't know why the following steps were pending. That's not what it is supposed to be like that..

I noticed that No step is matching in the story, that's not normal. However, checked all other files, can't figure out why. Could you please take a look at the following screenshots?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N59Gv.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD7oh.png)
[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzGIz.png)

Indeed, i don't know if there's any relationship between Pending issue and "No step is matching". However, "No step is matching" must be a problem to be resolved.

Comment: In the story you have: `Then the grid should look like`, without any parameter at the and, but in the class file you have `@Then("the grid should look like $grid")` - with `$grid` parameter at the end.

Comment: thank you kordirko. You're absolutely right. Thanks again and wish you happy new year ahead!